# Unhandled exception rendering component: The requested icon (ArrowCircleLeft, Size20, Regular) is not available in the collection

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, fluent-ui, fast-blazor

I'm studing Fluent UI Blazor component of Blazor WebAssembly App.

The browser throws the following error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The requested icon (ArrowCircleLeft, Size20, Regular) is not available in the collection
System.ArgumentException: The requested icon (ArrowCircleLeft, Size20, Regular) is not available in the collection
   at Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI.FluentIcon.OnParametersSet() in /_/src/Microsoft.Fast.Components.FluentUI/Components/Icon/FluentIcon.cs:line 92
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

This is my source code

```
<div style="display:flex">
    <FluentIcon Name="@FluentIcons.ArrowCircleLeft" />    
</div>
```

I am following the "https://github.com/microsoft/fast-blazor" site.

Buttons and other components work fine, only the icon gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the below document if you’re using hosted Blazor project with version 2.1 and higher

[fluentui-blazor/WHATSNEW.md](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui-blazor/blob/2ed253a99758d5647ba67ec75135ef4cea53779b/WHATSNEW.md)

Two additional configurations/changes are required in the project file and Program.cs